# Pyspark UDF unable to use large dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, pyspark, user-defined-functions, amazon-emr

I've a dictionary consisting of keys = word, value = Array of 300 float numbers. 
I'm unable to use this dictionary in my pyspark UDF.
When size of this dictionary is 2Million keys it does not work. But when I reduce the size to 200K it works.

This is my code for the function to be converted to UDF

```
def get_sentence_vector(sentence, dictionary_containing_word_vectors):
     cleanedSentence = list(clean_text(sentence))  
     words_vector_list = np.zeros(300)# 300 dimensional vector
     for x in cleanedSentence:
          try: 
               words_vector_list = np.add(words_vector_list, dictionary_containing_word_vectors[str(x)])
          except Exception as e:
               print("Exception caught while finding word vector from Fast text pretrained model Dictionary: ",e)
     return words_vector_list.tolist()
```

This is my UDF

```
get_sentence_vector_udf = F.udf(lambda val: get_sentence_vector(val, fast_text_dictionary), ArrayType(FloatType()))
```

This is how i'm calling the udf to be added as a column in my dataframe

```
dmp_df_with_vectors = df.filter(df.item_name.isNotNull()).withColumn("sentence_vector", get_sentence_vector_udf(df.item_name))
```

And this is the stack trace for the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/broadcast.py", line 83, in dump
    pickle.dump(value, f, 2)
SystemError: error return without exception set
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py", line 1957, in wrapper
    return udf_obj(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py", line 1916, in __call__
    judf = self._judf
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py", line 1900, in _judf
    self._judf_placeholder = self._create_judf()
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py", line 1909, in _create_judf
    wrapped_func = _wrap_function(sc, self.func, self.returnType)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py", line 1866, in _wrap_function
    pickled_command, broadcast_vars, env, includes = _prepare_for_python_RDD(sc, command)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2377, in _prepare_for_python_RDD
    broadcast = sc.broadcast(pickled_command)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 799, in broadcast
    return Broadcast(self, value, self._pickled_broadcast_vars)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/broadcast.py", line 74, in __init__
    self._path = self.dump(value, f)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/broadcast.py", line 90, in dump
    raise pickle.PicklingError(msg)
cPickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize broadcast: SystemError: error return without exception set
```

Comment: It's a problem with serialization. cPickle cannot handle big objects. Try broadcasting the variable to see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How big is your `fast_text_dictionary` in the 2M case? It might be too big. 
Try `broadcast` it first before running `udf`. e.g.

```
broadcastVar = sc.broadcast(fast_text_dictionary)
```

Then use `broadcastVar` instead in your `udf`.

See the [document for broadcast](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables)

Comment: Hi, size of the fast_text_dictionary is 100663576 Bytes. I'm getting the following error while broadcasting

py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.readBroadcastFromFile.
: java.lang.NullPointerException